# Intellij: Can't load module after unloading it

Tags: intellij-idea, module

To speed up Intellij (Build #IU-183.4588.61) I unloaded a bunch of modules. Now they do not show up on the right side of the load/unload dialog and I am unable to load them again.

[image]

Since Intellij specifically states these unloaded modules are not applied to any VCS I am unable to find the changed .xml file to revert it manually.

I would like to avoid having to re add them via the "From existing Source..." option.

Can I fix the load/unload feature somehow? If so, how?

Comment: If it is a Maven/Gradle project you can add module from Maven/Gradle tool window. Otherwise use File | New | Module form Existing Sources... action to add the module to an existing project.

Comment: It is not a Maven/Gradle project. I already thought of re-adding them this way, but I want to know if there is a way to fix the load/unload feature.

Comment: I have the same issue here. me too I don't wanna reimport the module again.